# How calculate correction factor from regression model?

Tags: r, regression

I meet the term "correction factor" (is it some ratio?) in many foreign publications, but I do not know how it is calculated.

I have some nonlinear regression model (power function) with fitted line to my data. One independent (X) and one dependent (Y) variable.

I need formula like these:

Corrected data = Measured data / (correction factor)

How to do this? I need correct data from my sensor.

My model:

```
Formula: Y ~ a * (X/100)^b

Parameters:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a  66.6224     1.1622   57.32   <2e-16 ***
b   8.0228     0.4258   18.84   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 23.14 on 998 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 8 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.854e-06
```

Many thanks.

Comment: General questions: do you know in what way the data should be changed by the correction factor? What would be the purpose of a correction factor in your work?  Your code shows "X/100", do you know the purpose of this scaling by 100? There should be a reason or purpose for scaling the data by a factor of 100 (or some other factor), knowing this will help answer your question.

Comment: Because the sensor reading increases with humidity (X).
I must to compensate this impact.
X/100 is a simple convert percentage, eg. 95% to 0.95.
My X (Humidity) is from 0-100% range.

Comment: I understand. Many industrial sensors also have a bias added to the output, so you might consider testing "Y ~ a * (X/100)^b + offset". If there is no sensor output bias, the fitted "offset" value will be very close to zero.

Comment: Sorry, i am beginner.
I have model and all data (first post).
I need only apply this observations to correct data.
What formula i must apply?
Corrected data = Measured data / (correction factor(X)???)

Comment: Can someone help me?